# Doing integration by parts on exponential families

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I have a problem of estimating moments of an exponential family by integration by parts.
Lets consider the exponential family in its canonical form.
$f(x)=e^{\theta x-\psi(\theta)}h(x)$.

The parameter is $\theta$. 
$x$ is univariate.

$\psi(\theta)$ is the normalizing constant.

I want to compute $E(x)$ by definition (the expected value of $x$).

**What I know**

I know that for exponential families $E(x^k)=\psi^k (\theta)$. Where $\psi^k $ represents the $k$th derivative of $\psi$.

Hence $E(x)=\psi^\prime(x)$.

To get $E(x)$ the proof starts by:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx=1$  (because $f(x)$ is a probability distribution) then differentiate both sides with respect to $\theta$ and more manipulations are done to get $E(x)=\psi^\prime(x)$

**What I will like to be helped on.**

Use the definition of the expected value to arrive at the same solution $E(x)=\psi^\prime(x)$.

That is show that $E(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x)dx=\psi^\prime(x)$.

I have tried to use integration by parts. But I get a $0$.

Can someone nicely use integration by parts to solve this.